# Events being not highlighted correctly in Fullcalnedar using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, events, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use fullcalendar with angularjs and when I pass events as follows it doesn't display in the calendar correctly

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$scope.calendarEl = "";
 $scope.calendar = "";
$scope.event = {events: [{
            title:'test1',
            start: '2019-05-05 21:00',
            end: '2019-05-06 00:00'
          },
          {
            title:'test2',
            start: '2019-05-05 12:00'
        }]};
    $scope.calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        $scope.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar($scope.calendarEl, {
            events: $scope.event.events,
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid','list' ]
        });
         $scope.calendar.render();
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <div id="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

So when the calendar is displaying both events the event title with **test1** **doesn't highlight both days 5 and 6th**. It only highlights day 5. But if I add the starting time as 00:30 then it highlight both days correctly. How can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: Read this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold

Comment: According to the documents default value is 00:00:00. Therefore the above event should be displayed correctly @ADyson

Comment: yes but since end dates are **exclusive** (again please take a moment to [read the relevant documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)), this means that in fact fullCalendar considers the final moment of your event to be at `2019-05-05 23:59:59` so in reality it will not be considered to occur on that day.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson I tried changing the nextDayThreshold to 23:59:59 but then none of the multivalues showed correctly.Any suggestions ?

Comment: Since that changes the minimum threshold to almost midnight at the end of the day then clearly nothing which is multi-day with an end date before midnight will appear on its final day. What were you expecting to happen?